# How to get the calendar week difference between two moments?

Tags: javascript, date, logic, momentjs

I want to get the calendar week difference between two dates in javascript.

Example:

```
a='09-May-2018'
b='14-May-2018'
```

Calendar week difference between these two is 2.

I started by converting date to moment and getting the difference in terms of weeks by Moment.js diff method. But that is considering 7 days as a weeks and giving me 1 for above example.

I thought of getting the week number of moment and then subtract it. But in that, if the date is of two different year. I will get wrong result. Like `'01-Jan-2017'` and `'01-Jan-2018'` will give week number as 1.

Is there any better way to do this efficiently?

Comment: How do you determine "calendar week"? Does the week start on Sunday or Monday? Is Sat 5 May to Mon 7 May 2 weeks?

Comment: @RobG I want first day as Sunday

Comment: Have you managed to find some nice and clean solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a requirement that, if difference is greater that 12 weeks I have to perform some action. 
So I did it by getting week by week() method of Moment. Like this:

```
Math.abs(endDate.diff(startDate, 'days'))<91 &&
  Math.abs(startDate.week() - endDate.week()) < 12)
```

Comment: Please accept this answer so that future readers know the solution of this problem.

Comment: How does this answer the question? How can you get the count or weeks between two dates using this? What if each week is in different year?

Answer (score 2):

You can also calculate week difference in plain javascript. Since you haven't fully explained the rules for how to determine the number of weeks I've made some guesses. The following:

1. Defaults the first day of the week as Monday
2. Copies the dates and moves them to the start of the week
3. Makes sure d0 is before d1
4. Calculates the number of weeks as `1 + (endDate - startDate) / 7`
5. The day for the start of the week can be set using an optional 3rd parameter: 0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, etc.
6. The result is always positive. If the dates are in the same week, the difference is 1.

This only works correctly if the end date is after the start date.

```js
/* Calculate weeks between dates
** Difference is calculated by getting date for start of week,
** getting difference, dividing and rounding, then adding 1.
** @param {Date} d0 - date for start
** @param {Date} d1 - date for end
** @param {number} [startDay] - default is 1 (Monday)
** @returns {number} weeks between dates, always positive
*/
function weeksBetweenDates(d0, d1, startDay) {

  // Default start day to 1 (Monday)
  if (typeof startDay != 'number') startDay = 1;

  // Copy dates so don't affect originals
  d0 = new Date(d0);
  d1 = new Date(d1);

  // Set dates to the start of the week based on startDay
  [d0, d1].forEach(d => d.setDate(d.getDate() + ((startDay - d.getDay() - 7) % 7)));

  // If d1 is before d0, swap them
  if (d1 < d0) {
    var t = d1;
    d1 = d0;
    d0 = t;
  }

  return Math.round((d1 - d0)/6.048e8) + 1;
}

console.log(weeksBetweenDates(new Date(2018, 4, 9), new Date(2018, 4, 14)));
```

Answer (score -1):

Using moment.js, according to https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/diffing/

```
/**
* @param fromDate - moment date
* @param toDate - moment date
* @return {int} diffInWeeks Diff between dates with weeks as unit
**/
const getDiffInWeeks = (fromDate, toDate) => {
    const requestedOffset = 1
    const diff = toDate.diff(fromDate);
    const diffInWeeks = moment.duration(diff).as('weeks')
    return Math.ceil(diffInWeeks) + requestedOffset
}
```

Comment: Your function returns 0.7142857142857143 while the thread owner wanted the result to be 2.

Comment: @shaedrich between May 9 and 14 may that would be the week diff. I am adding a comment in case someone would like to get 1. But why 2?

Comment: Because the thread owner wanted calendar weeks instead of n times 7. I'm just pointing out what the thread owner was asking for.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks @shaedrich. Updated with that goal.

Comment: I bet, it's more than an offset. It's another type of week: https://www.calendar-week.org/